# Take the whole line of a java chain and lenth

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java program that given a string, I return the length of it, but I do not know why it does not catch me all. I'm starting with the programing. I've got here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lengt {
public static void main (String [] args) {

Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
String cad = in.next();
System.out.println (cad);
System.out.println ("The length is:" + cad.length ());
}
}
```

Comment: *it does not catch me all*: what does that mean. What are you doing **precisely**, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Have you read the javadoc of Scanner and of Scanner.next()?

Comment: I try a simple program that prints the string by user and length

Comment: That's as vague as your question. What you should specify is something like that: "I run the program using the command `java lengt`. I enter the sentence *hello world* and then I press Enter. I expect the program to display *The length is:11* but instead the program stops and outputs *something went wrong*". See? that's a precise description. Is it really difficult?

Comment: @JBNizet - It may be really difficult for someone with poor English.  But ultimately that is the OP's problem to solve.  We can't answer his questions if they are not understandable.  (Maybe he would be better off with one of these: - Stack Overflow in Japanese: [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://jp.stackoverflow.com)
- Stack Overflow in Portuguese: [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)
- Stack Overflow in Russian: [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)
- Stack Overflow in Spanish: [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your solution. in.next(); just take the first word of the chain, the one that is most immediate. If instead of using that you put it in.nextLine(); It takes you all the line you enter. You also have to be careful with length, which goes from 0 to n-1, when it comes to taking the length, since you could take one more and unnecessary. The solution for the problem that you pose would be, and there may be more, but one valid

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
public static void main (String [] args) {
       Scanner in= new Scanner (System.in);
       String cad = in.nextLine();
       System.out.println (cad);
       System.out.println ("The length is:" + cad.length() - 1); //you can remove -1
       }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do that and it did not come out, thanks!